# Removing id from foreach if user_type is not 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a page with categories however in the foreach loop, I wish to remove one if the user does not have a user_type of 5, eg

the below is a simple laravel foreach

```
@foreach ($category as $cat)
  {{$cat->id}}
  {{$cat->title}}
  so on..
@endforeach
```

The category id i wish to remove is 1 unless they user_type is 5

```
$user->UserProfile->user_type 5
```

I think I have come up with something however not to sure if its the.. Best way of doing it.

```
@foreach ($category as $cat)
    @if($user->UserProfile->user_type !=5)
        @if($cat->id != 1)
          {{$cat->id}}
          {{$cat->title}}
        @endif
    @else
      {{$cat->id}}
      {{$cat->title}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: if/else statement?

Comment: what did you change till now? did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

propably in your controller you have this

**Controller**

```
Public function whatever() {

  $category = Categorie::all();

   if(Auth::user()->UserProfile->user_type !=5)
       {
        $category->forget('put right key here'); // dd the $category collection to get the right key
       }

   return View('hodor')->with('category',$category); // just do a simple loop in iew
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not query where not equal to?

```
if (Auth::user()->UserProfile->user_type !=5) {
    $categories = Categorie::where('id', '!=', $id);
} else {
    $categories = Categorie::all();
}

return View('hodor')->with('category',$category);
```